# How to get the argument passed from perl script to java file

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Windows 10 OS. I need to pass an argument from perl script to jar file which i have written as

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"
my @args = ("java", "-jar", "Authorize.jar","var");
system(@args);
```

Here 10 is the argument i need to pass to java file.How do i pass this argument to a function written in java file.The java file code is

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            boolean b = isUserLoggedIn();
}
```

in  isUserLoggedIn() i need to pass the value of parameter var(which is a dynamic variable) .Can anyone suggest me how i could do it.

Comment: Just use `args[0]`?

Comment: "$var" instead of "var"